# Microsoft Team 100% CPU usage

Tags: linux-mint, cpu-usage, microsoft-teams

Occasionally Microsoft Teams will decide to continuously utilize 100% CPU of one core and not stop unless it is killed.

Is there a better solution to this problem than to kill it and hope it won't do it again soon?

Comment: Is there a problem? What are the symptoms? Using 100% of a single core shouldn't be an issue unless you are experiencing crashes, system overheating etc.

Comment: 100% cpu usage of a single core in idle is a problem on my electricity bill/battery time!

Comment: What do you use Teams for? Does it happen when it's idle, or only when it's doing certain things?

Comment: Mostly video calls with many participants and sometimes chat. When I notice the high CPU usage via my monitoring it has always been when teams is idle. I haven't figured out how to trigger this, since it only happens when I'm not using teams.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is a known issue with Teams and Skype for Linux.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/5531/high-cpu-usage-continues-after-ending-video-call.html

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/all/high-cpu-usage-in-skype-for-linux-also-after-a/9ab671fb-fdcd-47b7-8ba2-4d3eb8bbba67?page=1

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/very-high-cpu-usage-in-teams-for-linux/m-p/1385536

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/908686-bug-reports/suggestions/40684789-high-cpu-on-linux-when-teams-is-idle

A few people have reported that deleting the cache directory for Teams fixes the high CPU utilization. It is unclear whether this is a permanent or temporary fix. On Ubuntu 18.04, the Teams cache is located at

```
~/.config/Microsoft/Microsoft\ Teams/Cache
```

If this doesn't work, and you need to join a Teams meeting on battery power, I'd suggest you use the Teams web app rather than the desktop app.